# Jupyter notebookよりVSCode経由の方がかなり遅い

Tags: python, vscode, jupyter-notebook

タイトルの通りなのですが、
Anacondaを用いてpythonをインストールしています。

Jupyter notebookの方が、
VSCode（F5実行）よりかなり実行が早いのですが、
そんなものなのでしょうか？？
（対話形式よりpy形式の方が普通軽い気がしますが・・・）

OS:Windows10
CPU:i3-2100@3.1GHz
memory:8GB

Comment: パフォーマンスについては、動かしているプログラムや時間計測の方法に左右されるところが大きそうです。可能であればどんなプログラムを動かしたときにどういう方法で計測するとどのくらい差があるのかを追記していただけませんか？　たとえば単に `print("Hello world")` するだけでも分かる程度の差でしょうか。Jupyter Notebookの場合、セル実行をどうやってるのかも気になります。

Comment: print出すだけでわかるぐらいの違いです。顕著なのがpandasで、jupyterはストレスなくcsvが読めるのに、VSCodeだと3秒ぐらいかかったりします。データ件数は数千件です。

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/31879/ なんて記事もあったし Windows のパイプを使っているか否かかもしれない（単に妄想）

Answer (score 1):

Windows7, memory:16G, CPU:Intel Xeon 2.27GHz
ですが、VScodeの実行はJupyterに比べて遅すぎます。

支障が出るほどとにかく遅いので、jupyterのほうがよいです。

インタプリタはどちらもAnaconda3です。